# sequential JQUERY smooth transition for IPAD

Tags: jquery, ipad

im creating this frame by frame fadein fadeout image but the problem is the ipad is rendering it very slow.is there a better way to do this
here is my code:

```
var counter = 1,
srcStr1 = "../img/landscape/p25/",
srcStr2 = ".jpg",
frames = $("<div id=\"frames\"></div>"),
removeFrame = function() {
    if (frames.children().length > 1) {
    frames.children(":first").fadeOut({},40).queue(function(nxt) { 
    $(this).remove();
    nxt();
});

} else {
    clearInterval(timer);   
       }
},
timer = setInterval(function() { removeFrame() },40);

////////create frames
for(var x = 3; x--;) {
$("<img />", {
src:  srcStr1 + counter  + srcStr2
}).css("zIndex", x).appendTo(frames);
counter++;}
frames.appendTo("#belo").fadeIn("slow");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter rendering artifacts on iOS due to the tiled rendering engine of the GPU not vsync-ing after the transition, the following may help:

```
<style type="text/css">
   html, body { -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); }
</style>
```